# Error when moving a user to a VC Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm learning Node.js and to train myself I wanted to code a Discord bot.

I want to all user that are in the VC of the `message.author.id` to an other VC. So I did this:

```js
members = message.member.voice.channel.members.map(user => user.id)
 
for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
                let memberID = members[i]
                let UserToMove= message.guild.members.cache.get(memberID)
                console.log(UserToMove)
                UserToMove.setChannel(ID)
                .catch(console.error)
            }
```

However, when I run the code, it throws this error:

```
(node:18576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: UserToMove.setChannel is not a function
```

I know what it means, but I don't know how I can resolve it.

Thank You

Comment: Yeah, i know. Thank You again. I didnt accept the request before because i had a cooldown of 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GuildMember` has no `setChannel()` method, only a [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel) has. You can try `UserToMove.voice.setChannel(ID)`. You could also simplify your code:

```js
const { members } = message.member.voice.channel;

members.each((member) => {
  member.voice.setChannel(ID).catch(console.error);
});
```